# Exchange Server EWS authentication configuration

Tags: exchange, authentication

How common is it for people to enable Basic authentication with Exchange Web Services?

I am looking to connect to Exchange Server from an app running on Windows Phone 7 which only supports Basic authentication.

The default configuration of an Exchange installation has Basic authentication disabled for the EWS virtual directory.

Do admins regularly enable Basic authentication or is it something that they will only do if they really have to?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Basic is enough if you using SSL. Encryption over Encryption. Don't see a reason for it.

Comment: Just to elaborate, Basic sends passwords in plaintext, which is why it's typically disabled, and a security risk unless you have encryption between the device and computer (SSL, etc.).

Comment: As much as I can recall, all the default settings are on Basic. Unless otherwise specified.